# how to hide a button according to the logged in user? inHTML

Tags: laravel

hello this problem arose, I want to hide this button according to the logged in user

this is how i have my code
.

this is how I verify my user @if (Auth::user()->idrol == 1)

but i want when
this is how I verify my user @if (Auth::user()->idrol == 2)

do not show the button

Comment: What is ```idrol``` ?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to check the user is login or not in blade using below code.

```
@if (Auth::check())
  //logged in user
@endif
```

For your question also it will become the answer. 
You will change your code like

```
@if (Auth::check())
  <button type="button" @click="abrirModal('articulo','actualizar',articulo)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
     <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
  </button> &nbsp;
@endif
```